# SD card is not detected in Wine software

Tags: wine, sd-card

I want to upgrade the maps for my cars navigation system. I have a laptop that runs Ubuntu, and has a SD card reader. I have installed the car manufactors software through Wine. When I plug in the SD card it gets detected by Ubuntu, but the car software is completly ignorant the fact that I connect a card. Nothing happens. I have seen in WineCFG and the SD port is listed as a station there. Anyone know what could be the matter here? My other Windows devices does not have an SD card reader.

Comment: This is the kind of software that typically doesn't work in Wine.

Comment: That sucks. Guess I’m buying an SD card USB reader then

Comment: If you can upgrade the maps by simply copying files and the navigator works as a normal mass storage device then you don't need that software, the Ubuntu file manager should be enough. But if it uses some proprietary connection/protocol and it needs special software to communicate with a PC (like Apple products and iTunes) then an SD card **won't work either**.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue updating my car navigation software too. I don't know about a direct answer to your question (about getting a WINE program to recognize an inserted SD card) but for me, I discovered a working solution.

In the settings of the navigation update app, there was an option to download update files to hard disk rather than install on the SD card. I did that, then quit and found the files in the WINE folder in the Ubuntu file manager. Just copy the files manually to the SD card, ensuring that the folder/directory structure is the same. At first my car navi didn't recognize the card because I needed the files to first be in a particular folder, so pay attention to the directory structure of the SD card **before** you wipe it and copy over the updated navi files.